# Use echo output as input into a script's stdin

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin

There is a script "X", which depending on input will export some environment variables.

To run "X" within another script "Y", I do the following:

```
echo "some input" > temp_file
source X < temp_file
```

Is there a alternative way to do this, without using temporary files?

As I understand in case of pipes a sub-process is created, and by running the following line

```
echo "some input" | source X
```

the environment variables can't be set or modified within a current script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
source X < <(echo "some input")
```

It basically allows you to redirect the input/output of a process to another process as if it were a file.